# Django - multiple url routers, same url?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url

So i am trying to have a server control page in a django applications with a list of servers that links via uuid to starting, cloning and stopping each respective server. (think a really terrible openstack UI). This is the code that generates the url.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'start' uuid=uuid %}">Start</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'clone' uuid=uuid %}">Clone</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'stop' uuid=uuid %}">Stop</a></li>
```

Unfortunately it would appear that when I click the clone link on the web application it starts rather than clones the server, meaning it is running the start function in view.

Here is how the urls are defined:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #url(r'^$', views.transfer, name='transfer'),
    url(r'^malware/$', views.malware, name='malware'), # Add this /malware/ route
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'), # Add this /about/ route
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.start, name='start'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.paranoidfish, name='paranoidfish'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.clone, name='clone'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.stop, name='stop'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.transfer, name='transfer'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I'm sure there's something basic i'm missing here, as always any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well those URLs are all the same. How are you expecting Django to know which one you have called?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the urls not being unique was the issue

This is how I solved the problem:

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^start/(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.start, name='start'),
url(r'^paranoidfish/(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.paranoidfish, name='paranoidfish'),
url(r'^stop/(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.stop, name='stop'),
url(r'^transfer/(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.transfer, name='transfer'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The template remained the same as it dynamically generates the URL pattern. Pretty nifty imo.